# Repeat program with different data

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to automatically repeat this program 10 times? Only each time changing `Login1`, `Password1` to `Login2`, `Password2`, next time `Login2`, `Password2` to `Login3`, `Password3` and so on.

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from Twitter_auth import Login1, Password1
from Proxy_auth import Log1, Pass1, IP1
import time
import pickle

capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
proxy = f"http://{Log1}:{Pass1}@{IP1}"
proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': proxy,
        'https': proxy
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options, seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
try:
    driver.page_load_strategy = 'none'
    driver.get(url="https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
    time.sleep(4)
    login_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "text")
    login_input.send_keys(Login1)
    time.sleep(2)
    login_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(4)
    password_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
    password_input.send_keys(Password1)
    time.sleep(3)
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(10)

    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(f"{Login1}_cookies", "wb"))
    time.sleep(5)



except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a dictionary that contains login and password data

```
Login = {'Login1': 'Password1',
         'Login2': 'Password2',
         'Login3': 'Password3',
         'Login4': 'Password4',
         'Login5': 'Password5',
         'Login6': 'Password6',
         'Login7': 'Password7',
         'Login8': 'Password8',
         'Login9': 'Password9',
         'Login10': 'Password10',
        }
```

Use for-loop like this:

```
for login, password in Login.items():
    
   # Use login and password instead of login1 and password1
```

Comment: But I don't understand how can I automatically run the code 10 times in a row, each time changing the password and login automatically

Answer (score 1):

The following would do the trick. Just create a list with all logins and passwords and the iterate over it with `for login, password in logins:`

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from Twitter_auth import (
  Login1, Password1,
  Login2, Password2,
  Login3, Password3,
  Login4, Password4,
  Login5, Password5,
  Login6, Password6,
  Login7, Password7,
  Login8, Password8,
  Login9, Password9,
  Login10, Password10,
)
from Proxy_auth import Log1, Pass1, IP1
import time
import pickle

logins = [
  [Login1, Password1],
  [Login2, Password2],
  [Login3, Password3],
  [Login4, Password4],
  [Login5, Password5],
  [Login6, Password6],
  [Login7, Password7],
  [Login8, Password8],
  [Login9, Password9],
  [Login10, Password10],
]

capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
proxy = f"http://{Log1}:{Pass1}@{IP1}"
proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': proxy,
        'https': proxy
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options, seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
try:
  for login, password in logins:
    try:
        driver.page_load_strategy = 'none'
        driver.get(url="https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
        time.sleep(4)
        login_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "text")
        login_input.send_keys(login)
        time.sleep(2)
        login_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(4)
        password_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
        password_input.send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(3)
        password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(10)

        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(f"{login}_cookies", "wb"))
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```